# 3D Position estimation using 2D camera

Tags: tracking, image-processing

I have a camera (iPhone), I have a 3D control object in the image that I know its properties very well. (My control object). There is also a secondary object in motion. The ultimate goal is to establish the 3D trajectory of the moving object for a given period of time. (Tracking)

I like to ask, could I find out?

- Phone's distance to the control object (for sake of discussion, let's assume camera is at certain height and certain distance neither of them is known but camera is perpendicular to the surface which is known)
- The secondary object where I can locate the object in each subsequent frame.  My goal is to estimate its 3D trajectory as I have indicated above.

Bonus question, we can make the system such that the phones distance to the control object can be set (although not preferred), would this help me with the second point?

Comment: Are you familiar with the literature in this area? If not I can recommend some papers, but be warned: the maths is involved.

Comment: @emre it would be great if you could provide some pointers. The math is no problem, we love math.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_tracking), [Recent advances and trends in visual tracking: A review](http://lshao.staff.shef.ac.uk/pub/Tracking_NeuCom2011.pdf) [PDF], [Bayesian Tracking for Video Analytics: An Overview](http://www.e-soto.com/publications/)

Comment: @emre I did take a quick look at the review paper.. This is more for tracking, I can track the object easily, that is not the issue. I can pin point in which pixel the object is. The issue is where the object is in 3D space. Is this possible? Basically, I have another object in 3D space that I know the properties which I can use as a frame of reference but that is it.

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong paper. Perhaps you can adapt [Vision-Based 3D Trajectory Tracking for Unknown Environments](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/06saeedi.pdf) [PDF]? They use a stereo camera; is that a possibility for you?

Comment: @emre I like to use iPhone. Stereo is not an option.

Comment: What is the control object?  Does it have a fiduciary marker? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWwp19ymChY

Comment: I'm trying something similar in a different context. Did you manage to do something with the answer below? Are you using OpenCV? Can you share a bit what you have done?

Comment: ## Excellence explanation. Could you please define What is K and R? ##

Comment: @Marcin : Welcome to DSP.SE! Please do not post answers as comments. You have a valid question. Please post it as a question an refer to the answer where those variables appear. Who knows? You might even get enough rep to comment then. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you object has 6 known points (known 3D coordinates, $X, Y$ and $Z$) you can compute the location of the camera related to the objects coordinate system.

First some basics.

Homogenous coordinate is vector presentation of euclidean coordinate $(X,Y,Z)$ in which we have appended so called scale factor $\omega$ such that the homogenous coordinate is $\textbf{X} = \omega \begin{bmatrix}X & Y & Z & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$. In your own calculations try to keep $\omega=1$ as often as possible (meaning that you "normalize" the homogenous coordinate by dividing it with its last element: $\textbf{X} \leftarrow \frac{\textbf{X}}{\omega}$). We can also use homogenous presentation for 2D points such that $\textbf{x} = \omega\begin{bmatrix}X & Y & 1\end{bmatrix}$ (remeber that these $\omega, X,Y$ and $Z$ are different for each point, be it 2D or 3D point). Homogenous coordinate presentation makes the math easier.

Camera matrix is $3\times4$ projection matrix from the 3D world to the image sensor:

$$
\textbf{x} = P\textbf{X}
$$

Where $\textbf{x}$ is the point on image sensor (with pixels units) and $\textbf{X}$ is the projected 3D point (lets say that it has millimeters as its units).

We remember that cross product between two 3-vectors can be defined as matrix-vector-multiplication such that:

$$
\textbf{v} \times \textbf{u} = \\
 ( \textbf{v} )_x \textbf{u} = \\
\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -v_3& v_2 \\
        v_3 & 0 & -v_1 \\
        -v_2 & v_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\textbf{u}
$$

It is also useful to note that cross production $\textbf{v} \times \textbf{v} = \textbf{0}$.

Now lets try to solve the projection matrix $P$ from the previous equations. Lets multiply the projection equation from the left side with $\textbf{x}$s cross product matrix:

$$
(\textbf{x})_x\textbf{x} = (\textbf{x})_xP\textbf{X} = \textbf{0}
$$

Aha! The result must be zero vector. If we now open the equation we get:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -w& y \\
        w & 0 & -x \\
        -y & x & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
            P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & P_{1,3} & P_{1,4} \\
            P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & P_{2,3} & P_{2,4} \\
            P_{3,1} & P_{3,2} & P_{3,3} & P_{3,4}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \textbf{X}
\\
=

\begin{bmatrix}
 P_{3,4} W y - P_{2,1} X w - P_{2,2} Y w - P_{2,4} W w + P_{3,1} X y - P_{2,3} Z w + P_{3,2} Y y + P_{3,3} Z y \\
 P_{1,4} W w + P_{1,1} X w - P_{3,4} W x + P_{1,2} Y w - P_{3,1} X x + P_{1,3} Z w - P_{3,2} Y x - P_{3,3} Z x \\
 P_{2,4} W x + P_{2,1} X x - P_{1,4} W y - P_{1,1} X y + P_{2,2} Y x - P_{1,2} Y y + P_{2,3} Z x - P_{1,3} Z y
\end{bmatrix} = \textbf{0}
$$

With little bit of refactoring we can get the projection matrix $P$ outside of the matrix:

$$
\tiny
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - X\, w & - Y\, w & - Z\, w & - W\, w & X\, y & Y\, y & Z\, y & W\, y\\ X\, w & Y\, w & Z\, w & W\, w & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & - X\, x & - Y\, x & - Z\, x & - W\, x\\ - X\, y & - Y\, y & - Z\, y & - W\, y & X\, x & Y\, x & Z\, x & W\, x & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{P}_1 \\
    \textbf{P}_2 \\
    \textbf{P}_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\textbf{0}
$$

Where $\textbf{P}_n$ is the transpose of $n$:th row of the camera matrix $P$. Last row of the previous (big) matrix equation is linear combination of the first two rows, so it does not bring any additional information and it can be left out.

Small pause so we can gather our toughs. Note that the previous matrix equation has to be formed for each known 3D->2D correspondence (there must be at least 6 of them).

Now, for each point correspondence, calculate the first two rows of the matrix above, stack the $2\times12$ matrices on top of each other and you get new matrix $A$ for which

$$
A\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{P}_1 \\
    \textbf{P}_2 \\
    \textbf{P}_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\textbf{0}
$$

As we have 12 unknowns and (at least) 12 equations this can be solved. Only problem is that we don't want to have the trivial answer where 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{P}_1 \\
    \textbf{P}_2 \\
    \textbf{P}_3 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \textbf{0}
$$

Fortunately we can use singular value decomposition (SVD) to force

$$
\|
\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{P}_1 \\
    \textbf{P}_2 \\
    \textbf{P}_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\|=1
$$

So to solve the the equations, calculate SVD of matrix $A$ and pick the singular vector corresponding to the smallest eigen value. This vector is the null vector of matrix A and also the solution for the camera matrix $P$. Just unstack the $\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{P}_1 & \textbf{P}_2 & \textbf{P}_3 \end{bmatrix}^T$ and form $P$.

Now you wanted to know the distance to the object. $P$ is defined as:

$$
P = K\begin{bmatrix}R & -R\textbf{C}\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\textbf{C}$ is the camera location relative to the objects origin. It can be solved from the $P$ by calculating $P$s null vector.

(Hartley, Zisserman - Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision)

Finally, when you calculate the cameras location for two frames, you can calculate the unknown objects locations (or locations of some of the points of the object) by solving two equations for $X$:

$$
\textbf{x}_1 = P_1 \textbf{X} \\
\textbf{x}_2 = P_2 \textbf{X} \\
$$

Which goes pretty much the same way as how we solved the camera matrices:
$$
(\textbf{x}_1)_xP_1\textbf{X} = \textbf{0} \\
(\textbf{x}_2)_xP_2\textbf{X} = \textbf{0} \\
$$

And so on.

Comment: Is it correct to say that your way to calculate the 3D position of the camera is equivalent to OpenCV solvePnp? http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html (search for solvePnP in the page. I can't paste a URL with a #)